# How to select a JRadioButton from ButtonGroup?

Tags: java, jbutton, jradiobutton

I try to do an image creator program in java (with squares/circles/etc)
I have a few JRadioButtons in a ButtonGroup that symbolizes my program's "mode" (if I draw a circle, something else/if I move the objects).
When I click on different modes, the "mode" changes and I'm able to do what I want. 
My problem is when I try to change the mode by double-clicking on an object. I do it in a MouseListener. I'm able to select the object, to change the "mode", but I can't change the selected JRadio Button on my ButtonGroup.
I searched for a while (since the setSelected() is not working). I know that ButtonGroup can have only a button selected at once. How could I deselect the curent one and select the one I need (the first one).
Thank you for any advices.

Comment: Use `isSelected();`, it will say the state of your `RadioButton`, if you use it on a loop you could know which one is slected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> public void setSelected(boolean b)
>
> Sets the state of the button. Note that this method does not trigger
>   an actionEvent. Call doClick to perform a programatic action change.

As mentioned here use:

```
radioBtn.doClick();
```

Comment: I had a few difficulties because my radioBtn did not have a name (created via a method and addes imediatly to the jFrame). I named every button and used radioBtn.doClick(1) to click the first one (the one I needed).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small method that allow me to set any radio group button. Very convenient if you don't want to use if for any radio button.

```
public void setButtonGroup(int rdValue, Enumeration elements ){
    while (elements.hasMoreElements()){
        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton)elements.nextElement();
        if(Integer.parseInt(button.getActionCommand())==rdValue){
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
setButtonGroup(yourValue, yourButtonGroup.getElements());
```